# Android exception when calling a new activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I'm trying really hard to create an instance. It works when I do not execute my code after the initial calling to the onCreate function. Logcat is throwing me a ton of useless errors( to me, at least). Here is the code I am calling

```
    String note=null;

    FileInputStream fip=null;
    try{        
       fip=new FileInputStream(this.getFilesDir()+"/currentNote");
    }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       //The first and probably last time this is useful
       note="";
   }
    try {
        while(fip.available()>0){
            byte current=(byte)fip.read();
            note=note+String.valueOf(current);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
            //Just... no
        }

    TextView note_display=(TextView) findVewById(R.id.note_input);
    note_display.setText(note);
```

Here is the logcat log:

```
 05-20 20:11:04.988: W/dalvikvm(20463): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410d9930)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buhala.notestaker/com.buhala.notestaker.ShowNote}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at com.buhala.notestaker.ShowNote.getText(ShowNote.java:36)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at com.buhala.notestaker.ShowNote.onCreate(ShowNote.java:22)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-20 20:11:05.008: E/AndroidRuntime(20463):    ... 11 more
```

( I tried hard on the formatting)
So, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is in line 36 of `ShowNote.java`?

Comment: Your `getText()` method returns null.

Comment: Did you declare the called activity in the manifest file ?

Comment: @Zakaria - if the activity were not declared in the manifest, there would be a line something like this `Have you declared your activity in the manifest` in the log

Answer (score 2):

Something in you code is null when you try to use it, which I what is causing the `nullPointerException`. I have two guesses;

Either, you are not calling `setContentView` until after you have declared your `TextView`, which will give you a null pointer exception

Or, you are running into an IOException, and your string remains null. This seems unlikely to me because I believe if you use `setText(null)` the output is simply null.

Comment: Yup, it plain old refused to happpen. I had to do one more check.
I had to add a terminate in the first catch block and if terminate=1, don't execute the second loop.

Comment: @user2402569 - Glad to hear you solved your problem. If you think the solution was worth of an answer, you can add your own answer, and in a few days accept if, to mark this question as solved and (possibly) help future visitors. Accepting an answer also gives you a nice 2 rep(and a badge for the first one I believe)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! If anyone is having the same problem, you are supoused to add a boolean value in the first try/catch place(if there is a file not found error, do not try to read from it. Don't know why that took me so long to figure out)

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException at your 'getText()' method on line 36.

Your initialisation of the FileInputStream object probably fails, hence it throws a FileNotFoundException. Therefore your FileInputStream object 'fip' is still 'null'.

Put all of the code in the same try block, like this:

```
try{        
       fip=new FileInputStream(this.getFilesDir()+"/currentNote");
       note = "";
       while(fip.available()>0){
            byte current=(byte)fip.read();
            note=note+String.valueOf(current);
        }
    }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       //handle exception
   }catch (IOException e) {
       //handle exception
   }
```